# Connect two Oracle Databases

Tags: oracle

I am not good at English please help me

I have two problems that I need help with.

I have two databases in one Oracle Server at IP 10.10.10.92

Table `One` has two columns `CustumerID` and `CustumerName` (Table One belongs to Database 1 named DB1).
Table `Two` has two columns `CustumerID` and `Job` (Table Two belong to Database 2 named DB2)

1. If I am using Oracle SQL Developer or TOAD for Oracle to query statements
    
   How can I connect from two table above?
2. If I am Using SQL Server 2005 to link two Oracle Database to query statements
   How can I connect from two table above?

Do I need to create two linked server or one linked server?

Comment: Do you really have two *databases* or do you have two schemas (=users). Can you show us the connectstring you use for those "databases"?

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly your question - you have Database 1 (DB1) and Database 2 (DB2) in the same server, each one of them has a customer table, right?

You can "connect" both database using a Database Link:

http://psoug.org/reference/db_link.html

I will assume that your users are named hr1 and hr2, respectively for DB1 and DB2.

Then it would be something like (in DB1):

CREATE DATABASE LINK to_db2 CONNECT TO hr2 IDENTIFIED BY hr2
USING DB2;

and in DB2

CREATE DATABASE LINK to_db1 CONNECT TO hr1 IDENTIFIED BY hr1
USING DB1;

For this to work you got to have both databases with the right TNS, or else you got to use a connection string instead of the database service.
After that you can query the other table:

### SELECT customer_name FROM customer_table@to_DB2 --connected to DB1.

EDIT:
After your edit:
 1. That would be the answer above, regardless of the IDE you use.
 2. Can you be more clear? You could create a view in DB1 to access DB2 and access that view from SQLServer.